# Are sqlcmd parameters inherently at risk of SQL injection?

Tags: sql-injection, injection, sql-server

The command line utility sqlcmd has a feature to allow parameter substitution, from command line parameters and environment variables. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx

If an attacker controls the variables, is there a way of writing the scripts so that they won't be vulnerable to SQL injection or is this inherently insecure in that situation?

Answer (score 3):

If the attacker controls SQLCMD inputs, then they can do anything their login credentials (authorized or stolen) can do.  That's just normal functioning.

**Don't do this.  This is a bad practice if there's any input from the outside going into your SQLCMD.**

If you insist on this, then if you want to use SQLCMD with parameter substitution from environment variables (perhaps), you probably want to experiment with credentials that can only EXECUTE within a certain, limited schema

```
CREATE SCHEMA FromSqlCmd AUTHORIZATION myuser

GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[FromSqlCmd] TO [myschema_execute];
```

Within each stored procedure, NEVER concatenate what's passed in to dynamic SQL.

NEVER put the results into a table without a whitelist; otherwise you're opening yourself up for second order sql injection.

If you're consider Powershell, then [cjsommer.com has an article about this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/cjsommercom/2015/10/13/running-parameterized-queries-against-sql-server-using-powershell/) - he found that neither powershell SQLPS command protected against injection, even with parameters.

---

## It's worse than that

If you actually let input - validated or not - from others be part of your command line for SQLCMD, then you're opening yourself up for command line injection!!!  The & character is one way for a command prompt to run multiple commands; try it with

```
C: & cd \ & format /? & del /?
```

Now imagine this in the middle of your sqlcmd.

Also note that Powershell uses ; to separate commands.